# Having trouble getting Checkbox value from GridView in Edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm trying to use Checkboxes in a gridview in order to update my database. Everything seems to be working perfectly, except getting the correct value from the Checkbox in edit mode.

Here is the relevant aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unlock" SortExpression="Unlock">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditUnlock" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Unlock")) %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUnlock" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Unlock")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Reset" SortExpression="Reset" DataField="Reset" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="false" />
```

I'm using the built in CheckBoxField and the TemplateField in hopes that one of them would work, neither did. I only get the original value from the checkbox. For example, if the checkbox is checked, and I uncheck it in Edit mode then press Update, The code reads it as being checked still.

Here is the RowUpdating Event for the gridview.

```
protected void grdManageActionGroups_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{           
    Label lblTargetGroupEdit = (Label)grdManageActionGroups.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblTargetGroupEdit");

    CheckBox chkEditUnlock = ((CheckBox)grdManageActionGroups.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkEditUnlock"));

    database.UpdateTargetGroup(ddlActionGroups.SelectedValue, lblTargetGroupEdit.Text, chkEditUnlock.Checked, (grdManageActionGroups.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked);
    FillTargetGroupsInGrid();
}
```

I would really appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem,

I needed to add

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
    FillTargetGroupsInGrid();
}
```

to the GridView's load event